# python - Expected dict, got list error

Tags: python, dictionary

In the below function there is a dictionary called `task_ranku{}`.

I'm trying to sort by its values and print the dictionary.

However, when I add these 2 lines to sort and print, I get the error `Expected dict, got list`

Could anybody explain what I am doing wrong?

```
cdef dict task_ranku_sorted = sorted(task_ranku.values())

  for key, value in task_ranku_sorted.iteritems():
      print key, value



def heft_order(object nxgraph, PlatformModel platform_model):

  """
  Order task according to HEFT ranku.

  Args:
    nxgraph: full task graph as networkx.DiGraph
    platform_model: cscheduling.PlatformModel instance

  Returns:
    a list of tasks in a HEFT order
  """

  cdef double mean_speed = platform_model.mean_speed
  cdef double mean_bandwidth = platform_model.mean_bandwidth
  cdef double mean_latency = platform_model.mean_latency

  cdef dict task_ranku = {}

  for idx, task in enumerate(list(reversed(list(networkx.topological_sort(nxgraph))))):

    ecomt_and_rank = [
      task_ranku[child] + (edge["weight"] / mean_bandwidth + mean_latency)
      for child, edge in nxgraph[task].items()
    ] or [0]

    task_ranku[task] = task.amount / mean_speed + max(ecomt_and_rank) + 1

  # use node name as an additional sort condition to deal with zero-weight tasks (e.g. root)
  return sorted(nxgraph.nodes(), key=lambda node: (task_ranku[node], node.name), reverse=True)
```

Comment: `sorted` just returns a list (with the sorted values in it), not the sorted whatever-type inside its brackets

Answer (score 0):

The task_ranku_sorted is not a dictonary, it is a list:

`task_ranku_sorted = sorted(task_ranku.values())`

as you call values() on your original dictionary and sort only the value list.

You can check it:

`print type(task_ranku_sorted)`

Answer (score 0):

`cdef dict task_ranku_sorted = sorted(task_ranku.values())`
This will give the sorted list of values so, `task_ranku_sorted` is a list of sorted values.

and on that your using function `iteritems()` .This function is only allowed for or applicable for `dict` type variable not for `list` and your using it for `list` which is `task_ranku_sorted.iteritems()` that is why you are getting this error.

If you want to sort dictionary see following functions:

```
import operator
sorted_dictinory = sorted(dictinory.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

OR

```
sorted_dictinory = sorted(dictinory.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

OR

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sorted_dictinory = OrderedDict(sorted(dictinory.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```